# Customising waveform-playlist plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins

I have a challenge on working on https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist

if you are going through the demo you can see that it is web audio editor. i just need to reconstruct it. In the sense if you are seeing the waveform playlist, you can see four type of audios. vocals, guitar, pianos and bass. After customisation, their will be only one row and into that row we can add multiple audios and we should be able to create new music as previous and the music should be able to overlap in the same row and should work as previous.

How can i customise a plugin like that. If you had did some customisation in a plugin before, you can give me an idea how to do and also let me know is it possible to do that like what i said.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a library that does the visual part of what you are looking for. [waveshaper-dom](https://github.com/Idicious/waveshaper-dom) is a full touch support waveform editing library (work in progress, [demo](https://idicious.github.io/waveshaper-demo/)), [waveshaper](https://github.com/Idicious/waveshaper) contains all the core algorithms with no browser dependencies if you want to implement your own visualization / interaction. You will want to split out the handling of audio to another library (I'm using the amazing [Tone.js](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js) for audio)

What the problem boils down to is that you have multiple segments of audio spread over multiple tracks. The minimal representation of a segment would be:

- start - Start time in seconds
- offsetStart - Offset from start in seconds, resize support
- end - End time in seconds
- trackId - Reference to track
- audioId - Reference to audio file
- index - Used to resolve overlapping segments

The first thing you have to do is to flatten the segment array for each track so that all overlaps are removed, the original segment array must be preserved. You can use a variant of an interval merge algorithm [link](https://github.com/Idicious/waveshaper/blob/master/src/methods/flatten.ts).

Secondly you will need an algorithm that takes the flattened segment list, a list of arguments (zoom level, scroll position for virtual scrolling, detail level etc) and access to the actual audio files. The algorithm should return an array with draw data (one set of data for each pixel to draw) that is then used as input for the render function. 
Considering each second of audio is +- 44100 data points, optimizing this algorithm is very important.

For interaction you can use a library like [hammerjs](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/tree/master/) to listen for touch/mouse events, update the segment(s) based on this, then flatten + calculate + render again.

In order to play it iterate over the flattened segments, for each create an AudioBufferSourceNode which you start with the start, offset and duration of the segment. A track is a node or set of nodes that a group of segment nodes is routed through that outputs to the AudioContext destination.